# Can't get Android text to speech to read on start of an activity without a button using a text or JSon file

Tags: java, android, json, text-to-speech

Here is what I am trying to do I would like to have TTS ask a question on the activity start to begin a dialog. I have found tons of articles on how to do something similar with user input in EditText and a button but I want to have TTS read from a text file preferably a Json file i'm not sure what I am missing, bare in mind I am not a programmer I pieced this together from a bunch of different articles.

```
TextToSpeech myTTS;
InputStream stream;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aibutton);

    myTTS=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitActivity() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            }
        }
    });

    stream.setOnActivityListener(new Stream.OnActivityListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnInitActivity(View v) {
            String toSpeak = stream.getText().toString();
            InputStream stream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stringquestions);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myTTS.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    });
}

public void onPause(){
    if(myTTS !=null){
        myTTS.stop();
        myTTS.shutdown();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

// act on result of TTS data check
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
            myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            // no data - install it now
            Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }
    }
}

// setup TTS
public void onInit(int initStatus) {

    // check for successful instantiation
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if (myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to 1) include the entire activity code, 2) fully describe the behavior you expect, and 3) fully describe the behavior you're getting and exactly at what point that it deviates from what you expected.  To narrow down the problem yourself, you could try temporarily reducing your requirements and building an absolute bare minimum program, for example, that just says "hi." and that is all... then add the remaining pieces from there.  Also adding more debug toasts (like the "sorry! speech failed") will help verify that the functions are even being called in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Move the tts speak code inside onInit code. 
 The tts speak method works only after onInit has been called.

 myTTS=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitActivity() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            stream.setOnActivityListener(new Stream.OnActivityListener() {
               @Override
               public void OnInitActivity(View v) {
                  String toSpeak = stream.getText().toString();
                  InputStream stream = 
                    this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stringquestions);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  myTTS.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
});
        }
    }
});
```